# Link in comment returns false 404

Tags: support, comments, links

On [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103561/when-i-stretch-a-rubber-band-it-breaks-when-i-hold-the-broken-ends-together-w/103565?noredirect=1#comment211682_103565) here, I posted a link to the famous xkcd. What is weird is, the link is broken, with a 404 error.

However if you remove the trailing `/` from the link it goes to the page correctly, even though the browser adds `/` anyway.

Also, [here is a sample link](http://what-if.xkcd.com/54/) which works. It is to the same page. **Probable bug report**.

Answer (score 4):

Using my moderator superpowers I have removed the trailing slashes. There also seemed to be some invisible characters there. In any case, both links seem to work now.

Comment: +1 for fixing. I want to give another +1 for superpowers.